# How is this variable sharing actually working in this package import?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, namespaces

I'm struggling a bit to understand how this variable is able to be shared in this package setup I have. It is working fine using the standard `config.py` module, but I can't wrap my head around "why" it is working.

Here is my current simple package setup (code for each module is placed under the module for better readability here):

```
test/
    __init__.py
        from test import config
        config.username = "username-init"

    config.py
        username = "username-config"

    main.py
        from test import config
        print(config.username)  # prints "username-init"
```

In Python, when I run `from test import main` , here is what happens (learned by putting extra `print()` statements in each module to see what is happening):

1. `__init__.py` runs first, which makes sense with the `from test` part of the import statement.
2. `__init__.py` imports `config.py`
3. `config.py` runs which sets the username variable to the initial value of `username-config`
4. So at this point, `__init__.py` has the username variable in its global namespace.
5. `main.py` finally runs, which once again runs `from test import config`
6. `main.py` prints `config.username` which returns the edited value `username-init`

My question centers around step 5 above. By putting extra `print()` statements in each module, I can see that when `main.py` runs its `from test import config` line, `__init__.py` is not run a second time as it was the first time in Step 1 above. Why wouldn't `main.py` have to run `__init__.py` also since the `main.py` namespace would have no knowledge of anything in `__init__.py` ? Certainly my Python session's global namespace now has knowledge of `__init__.py` after Step 1 above, but the `main.py` module's namespace would not, so when `main.py` encounters its own `from test import config` line it would need to run `__init__.py` as was done in Step 1, correct?

Answer (score 0):

A module is just **executable** code which typically involves creating useful objects and putting them in its namespace.  If you executed the module’s code again every time it was imported, you would end up with multiple versions of every class (which wouldn’t work properly when used together) as well as of every bit of mutable state (which is even worse than having mutable global state in the first place).  There are also cases where the runtime and memory usage would be exponential in the depth of the imports.

Of course Python doesn’t do this; **`sys.modules`** stores modules already imported and provides them for reuse by further importers.

Comment: Ah ok, so when `main.py` is importing `__init__.py` a second time, it doesn't have anything to do with whether the `main.py` module's namespace contains the `__init__.py` module already, but it is "Python itself" that sees that `__init__.py` has already been imported. SO, when `main.py` tries to import `__init__.py` it a 2nd time overall (but the first time for `main.py` itself), does Python simply pass the cached version of `__init__.py` to `main.py` for its use in its `main.py` module code?

Comment: @JonesSmith: Yes, and the same applies for `test.config`, which is the module that actually gets assigned in `test.main`’s namespace.

Comment: Ok great! I think maybe I was thinking of modules as being too isolated and not thinking of them in terms of the overarching Python program that is running the module code. It would be like someone (Python) assembling a chair and there are multiple different instruction sheets (modules) that call for other instruction sheets or tools to be used (or "imported") to assemble the chair.

Comment: (cont'd) The instruction sheets (modules) wouldn't make sense in the absence of someone to use them (Python), and it also helps make sense why module code isn't run twice as it wouldn't make sense to grab a 2nd screwdriver when another instruction sheet (module) already told you to grab an identical screwdriver, or if Instruction Sheet 2 told you to grab Instruction Sheet 1 again, you wouldn't make a copy of Instruction Sheet 1 because you already have it, so you would just use the one you already have.